# What is the explicit formula for the nth nonsquare and nth noncube?

Tags: functions

By a nonsquare(noncube) I mean a natural no. which is not a perfect square(perfect cube).For example the first few terms of the 2nd. sequence are 2,3,4,5,6,7,9,..
How can we derive the expression for the nth nonsquare and the nth noncube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the $n$'th non $k$-power, we can derive the following:
The $n$'th power of $k$ happens at $n^k$. The sequence of non-$k$-powers always increases one, except when passing a $k$-power. Without further ado, here is a formula (where the first term is $f(1)$):
$$
f(n)=n+\left\lfloor \sqrt[k]{n+\lfloor\sqrt[k]n\rfloor}\right\rfloor
$$
The part within the outermost root is a first formula, but it won't work, because it increases the sequence on term $4$, $9$, $25$, etc for the non-squares, but the $25$'th term is $28$, because you already passes three squares. Therefore, we supply the first formula as index for the good one.

I hope this is understandable. If not, try to understand what happens below. The first column is $n$, the second one the wrong formula $n+\lfloor\sqrt kn\rfloor$ and the last column the right formula.
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 2 \\
 2 & 3 & 3 \\
 3 & 4 & 5 \\
 4 & 6 & 6 \\
 5 & 7 & 7 \\
 6 & 8 & 8 \\
 7 & 9 & 10 \\
 8 & 10 & 11 \\
 9 & 12 & 12 \\
 10 & 13 & 13 \\
 11 & 14 & 14 \\
 12 & 15 & 15 \\
 13 & 16 & 17 \\
 14 & 17 & 18 \\
 15 & 18 & 19 \\
 16 & 20 & 20 \\
 17 & 21 & 21 \\
 18 & 22 & 22 \\
 19 & 23 & 23 \\
 20 & 24 & 24 \\
 21 & 25 & 26 \\
 22 & 26 & 27 \\
 23 & 27 & 28 \\
 24 & 28 & 29 \\
 25 & 30 & 30 \\
 26 & 31 & 31 \\
 27 & 32 & 32 \\
 28 & 33 & 33 \\
 29 & 34 & 34 \\
 30 & 35 & 35 \\
 31 & 36 & 37 \\
 32 & 37 & 38 \\
 33 & 38 & 39 \\
\end{array}
$$

(How can I partially hide this list and make it visible by clicking on it? Or is something like that not possible?)

Here is a [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/619236/91741) to an answer of me to a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution.Can you please tell me some book/reference where I can  have the proof of the a formula for f(n)

Comment: @sajjadveeri see my edit.